# apt error on Raspberry Pi 3 Parrot Security OS

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3, apt

I have a little problem. When i try to do apt update, install or anything, at the end this error shows:

> W: http: aptMethod::Configuration: could not load seccomp policy: Invadlid argument
>
> W: http: aptMethod::Configuration: could not load seccomp policy: Invadlid argument
>
> W: store: aptMethod::Configuration: could not load seccomp policy: Invadlid argument

Everything is fine, except for this little error that wasn't showing on any other system. Also I have problems running Firefox and Chrome, but I will ask a different question about these ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and found this post from Julian Klode who coded the warning:

"It means your kernel does not support seccomp, or you are using an emulation layer that does not support seccomp.

It is not an error. It is a warning I added temporarily to see if turning that off for people who do not have seccomp works correctly. It will go away in a later apt release."

https://github.com/meefik/linuxdeploy/issues/869

Answer (score 0):

Parrot is not designed for Raspberry Pi. It's for amd64 or i386 but not arm64. I'll recommend to go for kali since they support Pi. Check in [www.offensive-security.com](http://www.offensive-security.com)